# Is there a Gronwall-type lower bound inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

There are various versions of Gronwall's lemma. One of them is something like the following:

> If $f(t) \leq h(t) + \int_0^t g(s)f(s)ds$, plus some continuity
>   conditions, then $f(t)\leq$ something in terms of $g$ and $h$.

My question: is there something like what I have above with "$\leq$" replaced by "$\geq$"? I'm guessing not, but I'd like some more-than-hunch evidence.

Comment: How about applying Gronwall to $\tilde{f} = -f$? this will gives you a minoration

Comment: Oh, I guess so. Thanks!